# ExtJs from submit with fileupload filed on Different domain

Tags: extjs4

I have form submit method on which  I'm submitting form to different domain.
My form includes fileupload field . Due to fileupload field only I'm not able to take response back from third party domain. I have checked it on localhost it works perfectly but on different domain it gives error like

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "url".
```

And this also

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL "URL-1" from frame with URL "URL-2". Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Thanks in advance.